# YII2 add a sum column in the gridview

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How to add a sum column in the gridview?? I have a table with the a `grant_amount`, and `lcc_amount`. I want to add grant and lcc and display it in the gridview. How is that done?
I have successfully displayed already the data from the table to the gridview perfectly.

[image]

Comment: So it's just a sum of `Sp Grant` and `Lcc` column values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need set new column and set `value`, `label` property like that:

```
'columns' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                'id',
                ...
                'grant_amount',
                'lcc_amount',                    
                [
                    'label' => 'Sum',
                    'value' => function ($model) {
                        return $model->grant_amount + $model->lcc_amount;
                    }
                ],
```

For more [doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#grid-columns)

Comment: What should I do so that the sorting and searching in total column works.

Comment: I guess that is not what I need.... is it possible to add new variable in the searchcontroller and set its value to lcc + grant? How can that be done?

Comment: `grant_amount` and `lcc_amount` it is fields a one table?

Comment: i solved it using     $dataProvider->sort->attributes['total'] = [
        'asc' => ['(sp_grant + lcc)' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['(sp_grant + lcc)' => SORT_DESC],
    ];

Comment: @vitalik_74 Thanks for the solution. But if I want the calculated value to be stored in the model which already contains a sum column in the db. How can I do that? Can you help me please?